# Employee time tracker alternative

Tags: software-recommendation

Due to Covid19 situation our company has arranged home office for every employee. They use software named ActivTrack to keep records of working time, browsing history, idle time, used apps, browser tabs etc. This software has Windows and mac clients. As a long time Linux user I can't put up with Windows (which I am forced to use sadly).

I want to know if there is any software I can suggest that can do similar things but which is also installable in Linux?

[ActivTrack link](https://activtrak.com/) for reference.

Comment: It sounds like this is not just an app, but an app *and a service* that your company is using to bring that dreaded office micromanagement into the comfort of your home :( Unless there is an API, and a native linux client, it's unlikely that you'd be able to interact with the service, but it does appear from the website that there are mobile apps

Comment: Just to understand, you are forced to use Windows for work, and this app has a Windows client. What do you need a Linux software for then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also toss two more in the mix:

1. [Workpuls](https://www.workpuls.com/)
2. [Hubstaff](https://www.hubstaff.com)

I have used each of them as a freelancer and can recommend either over Time Doctor for their ease of use and features, not sure which to give the slight edge to,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternatives according to the "[Alternative To](https://alternativeto.net/software/activtrak/)" site. As this is also a list for posterity, I'd suggest checking the link to see if there are updates and additional choices added. If you know/find alternatives, you can help out the web by adding them to the site.

On that site there are *currently* three choices. I have tried exactly none of them.

1. [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/)
2. [ManicTime](https://www.manictime.com/)
3. [Time Doctor](https://www.timedoctor.com/)

Again, I've never tried any of them. I've employed many people and found that I got better results by letting them have some control over when the work was completed. After all, I was paying them to *do something* and not paying them to *just be present* at specific times. So long as they got their work done, done well, and done on time, I was pretty lenient. It worked for me.